# 2 Page Report per record

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am having issues recreating an old report with SSRS.  The original report would pull about 5-6 records from SQL, and then have a corresponding 2 page report for each record.  This would be easy if I could just create an individual report for each record, which is possible, but is not what is being asked of me.

I need to be able to have 2 pages for each record I return.  For example:

Page 1 will have a different table than page 2 for the same record and will be view-able as:

record 1:
page 1,2

record 2:
page 3,4

record 3:
page 5,6

No grouping is necessary for records.  They just need multiple pages to repeat.

Someone I work with suggested a sub-report, but I'm not sure how that would work.

I use the report builder to create reports.

Thanks for any help.  I will gladly clarify if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The nature of SSRS is that it grows based on whatever data is available when it is run. In order to force it to take up two pages per record, you'll need to set a placeholder. One way to do that is to have a table that spans two pages. Make sure the "CanShrink" property is set to False for the cells in at least one of the columns. You can remove the borders to make the column invisible if the length of the report varies.

Next, you can add columns as needed for your other report data. It doesn't really matter if you want to use a subreport or not, either way will work.